Mortgage forbearance a 2nd time after COVID forbearance
I recently entered into a streamlined modified loan agreement with my mortgage lender, following my use of the maximum allowed period of COVID forbearance.
If in the near future, I was to become unemployed, is it likely that i would be approved for another forbearance or deferment?

The answer to your query will be highly dependent on the laws of your state/country and the policies of your particular mortgage lender.  As you have not provided any of these details, it's difficult to see how anyone can provide a meaningful answer to you.
